# Unable to keep the table column width fix with CSS colgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

```css
p {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100px;">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:20px;">
      <col style="width:40px;">
        <col style="width:40px;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>
        <p>johntheman@example.com dsdsdsdsdsd dsdsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddsd dsdsssssssssssssdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds
          sadddddddddddddddddddddddddd
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have simple table with fix width. I also have fix width for columns in it to do that I have used CSS colgroup.

**Problem 1:**

Width of my columns if I check in developer's tool is different than that of what I have given in colgroup.

**What I have tried**

While fixing it I have found that the width changes with the text in it if I increase the text td increases and vice versa.

**Problem 2:**

When I enter the text in td unless I don't break it on new line by hitting enter the width of td goes on increasing with text.

**What I have tried**

To tackle this problem I have wrap my text in a p tag with fix width and then put it in td but still no luck. What I see is width is getting applied to P tag but text is overflowing.

**What I expect :**

I would like to know that why text is not breaking itself on new line after the fixed width of td. Why text overflows out of P even after fix width? Why td has to increase even after fix width?

I don't know what I am missing to apply here.

Comment: I think posting some relevant code would help, no?!

Comment: @ A. Wolff  that was unintentional  my apologizes i missed the code while posting added now .

Comment: Is that what you are looking for as behaviour: `td {
      overflow: auto;
    }` ?

Comment: no i want to know the reason why the width of my td is not equal to that of colgroup and second how can i mange to break my text automatically on new line within the fixed width td

Comment: But the TDs width is like expected, not increased. Only the text overflow it so i'm really not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: if you inspect the name column its width is 51px which is because of the big text NAME.but in the colgroup i have set the width of second column to 20px so why it is going to 51px ,why after 20px say ME letters come down from NAME

Comment: So use `table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}` has in posted answer below. And second column is 40px, not 20px. And anyway in chrome, there is not this behaviour (as i understand what you mean): `why after 20px say ME letters come down from NAME`

Answer (score 1):

for the table use css property

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Then provide fixed with to your td columns.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the `<p>` tag and `<td>` are fixed they are not increasing.

Until there is no space in your text content it will not wrap to next line. You have to use ellipsis which will put ... in place of overflowing text content. Use below css for your `<p>` tag.

```
p {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;       
}
```